# Return proper column based on other column's values

Tags: mysql, select, eav

Consider an EAV table with separate columns for each datatype:

```
CREATE TABLE eav_values (
    id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    entity_id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL,
    type SET('varchar','int','datetime') NOT NULL,
    col_varchar VARCHAR(1023) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    col_int INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    col_datetime DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now I'd like to store the `username` column for `entity_id=5`, which is a VARCHAR:

```
INSERT INTO eav_values (entity_id, name, type, col_varchar)
    VALUES (5, 'username', 'varchar', 'jeffatwood');
```

How would one construct the SELECT statement to select from the proper column with a single query?

```
SELECT (MAGIC HERE) FROM eav_values
    WHERE entity_id=5 AND name='username' LIMIT 1;
```

Might I be best off simply COALESCEing the values and carefully managing the data in application code? Is there no real performance penalty to such a SELECT?

```
SELECT COALESCE(col_varchar, col_int, col_datetime) FROM eav_values
    WHERE entity_id=5 AND name='username' LIMIT 1;
```

Or perhaps duplicate the data into a redundant `read` VARCHAR column for reading?

```
INSERT INTO eav_values (entity_id, name, type, col_varchar, read)
    VALUES (5, 'username', 'varchar', 'jeffatwood', 'jeffatwood');

SELECT read FROM eav_values
    WHERE entity_id=5 AND name='username' LIMIT 1;
```

Note that I would like to use different datatypes for each value as in some cases I might need to index or perform datype-specific logic on certain columns, in those cases I'll know which datatype or I'll use a separate SELECT to get the column type.

Comment: Condolences -- You are walking down a torturous trail -- EAV.

Comment: @RickJames: Pointers appreciated. So far I've been able to do what I need with subqueries but if you have any advice or tips they would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Follow the [eav] tag.

Comment: Even more discussion in stackoverflow.org tagged [mysql] [entity-attribute-value] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CASE type 
WHEN 'varchar'  THEN col_varchar 
WHEN 'int'      THEN col_int 
WHEN 'datetime' THEN col_datetime 
END
```